# SQL Count producing incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql, count, relational-database

I'm trying to calculate the number, and types of workers in a particular work slot.

There are two types of worker. Senior and Junior. The code should count how many Senior and Junior employees there are in a slot separately.

I've built a relational database in MySql. The relevant tables are **worker** - **slotwork** - **slot** where there is a many-to-many relationship between worker and slot. Many workers can be in an individual slot.

The results from the SQL are disturbingly inconsistent. Sometimes the count of employees is completely correct. Sometimes it appears entirely incorrect.

The simplest instance of this that I can find is as follows:

The SQL for calculating the number of junior workers is

```
SELECT slotwork.FK_SlotNo, Count(CASE WHEN worker.junior = 1 THEN 1 END) 
AS worker_count 
FROM worker 
INNER JOIN slotwork ON worker.EmployeeID = slotwork.FK_worker GROUP BY slotwork.FK_SlotNo;
```

There are no junior employees currently recorded in any slot, yet this returns result that looks like

```
SlotID worker_count
445 0
446 0
447 0
448 0
452 1
453 0
454 0
455 0
456 0
457 0
458 0
459 0
460 1
461 0
464 0
465 0
466 0
467 0
...
```

Let's take 4 of those slots above. 445, 452, 460, and 463.

```
445 is 0 ... correct.   There are 0 junior workers, and 5 senior workers.
452 is 1 ... incorrect. There are 0 junior workers, and 4 senior workers.
460 is 1 ... incorrect. There are 0 junior workers, and 4 senior workers.
463 is 0 ... correct.   There are 0 junior workers, and 3 senior workers.
```

Running the code to determine number of senior workers is mostly correct (Count(CASE WHEN worker.junior = 0 THEN 1 END)), but again with noticeable discrepancies.

Let's take the same slots as before

```
445 is 5 ... correct.   There are 0 junior workers, and 5 senior workers.
452 is 3 ... incorrect. There are 0 junior workers, and 4 senior workers.
460 is 3 ... incorrect. There are 0 junior workers, and 4 senior workers.
463 is 3 ... correct.   There are 0 junior workers, and 3 senior workers.
```

What might be generating these discrepancies?

The table for workers is structured as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `worker` (
  `EmployeeID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fullname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `junior` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Where junior is a boolean

Sample data can be found at https://pastebin.pl/view/832895ab

Comment: Please provide sample data.  Your `COUNT` expression is correct, and should only generate a non zero count for those `FK_SlotNo` groups having some records with `junior = 1`.

Comment: What's the data type of worker.junior?

Comment: At least show some sample input data?  Say, for the 4 `FK_SlotNo` in question, and all associated worker records?  You should give enough information for us to reproduce this case in dbfiddle or similar : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Stumbler Doesn't help, at all.  What's more, there seems to be no `junior` column in your sample data.  Please show us the real data in your question.

Comment: The sample data in your pastebin link do not contain the table worker.

Comment: @forpas fixed https://pastebin.pl/view/832895ab

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen https://pastebin.pl/view/832895ab

Comment: In the new sample data there are only 0s in the results: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2fuMcuMykFNGYWaBFXN8yU/1

Comment: @forpas oh this is very frustrating. When I run the code on my server it is convinced that 452 has 1 in it. There is no earthly reason why it should

Comment: Check if other values exist: `select * from worker where junior is null or junior <> 0 or junior <> 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think the count is making the problem.

```
  select count(CASE WHEN 'a' = 'b' THEN 1 else 0 END) as worker_count;
  Result --> 1
  select sum(CASE WHEN 'a' = 'b' THEN 1 else 0 END) as worker_count;
  Result --> 0
```

Add a junior worker and a slot then try the below query

```
SELECT slotwork.FK_SlotNo, sum(CASE WHEN worker.junior = 1 THEN 1 else 0 END) 
AS worker_count 
FROM worker 
INNER JOIN slotwork ON worker.EmployeeID = slotwork.FK_Employee 
GROUP BY slotwork.FK_SlotNo;
```

The existing query will be inconsistent because of Count() function, it will count on 0s and 1s in this case.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay - would you be able to elaborate? It predominantly counts up the number correctly: do you think you've identified something that explains its inconsistency?

Comment: Your count is the same as `count(*)` because you never return a NULL, you must remove the `else 0` (which didn't exist in the original query)